# How to loop through the same cells in specified columns

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following VBA to loop through the same cells in each column from column 2 to 1002. That is, in the coding, when i=2, I have Range("B3", "B1298"); when i=3, I need to have have Range("C3", "C1298"), and so on. How to achieve this, please? Thank you.

```
Sub ForwardRScen()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 2 To 102

        Range("ChgBP").Value = Sheets("sth").Cells(2, i).Value
        Sheets("sth").Range("B3", "B1298").Value = Range("DResults").Value

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: use [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)

Comment: @Banana any example code?

Comment: `Sheets("sth").Range("B3", "B1298").Offset(0,i).Value = Range("DResults").Value` and adjust `i` accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a range and changing it in the loop is a good way to go:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 12
        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(1298, i))
        myRange = i
    Next i

End Sub
```

This is what you will get:

[image]